# ASP.NET WFC Method not found with 404 resource not found error

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-services, wcf

I'm going crazy with this issue:
I've wrote this code:

```
[ServiceContract]
 public interface Idata
    {
     [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "getwinelist", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        List<Wine> GetWineList();
    }
```

and in my web.config file, I've this:

```
<services>
  <service name="WineFid.data">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WineFid.Idata" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
      </service>   
    </services>
```

with my behaviour:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
   <behavior name="webBehaviour">
       <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
```

If I point to https://host.mydomain.net/main.svc it works perfectly and show me the classic Microsoft page for web services, but when I point to the method:

```
https://host.mydomain.net/main.svc/getwinelist
```

The server responds with "404 resource not found...."
Where is my error?
Note that the service is hosted on Azure

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea on azure. Here is what i think can be the reason for resource not found error, try adding below line under tag `<endpointBehaviors>` and try if this can help.

```
<webHttp helpEnabled="true"  automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.... after liters of coffee and stomac medicines!!!

The problem was caused from the https protocols...

So was enough to add

```
 <security mode="Transport" />
```

inside the   node

```
 <webHttpBinding>
      <binding> 
            <security mode="Transport" />
```

Fiuuuuu.... Thanks to all for your attention!